# <!DOCTYPE html> alterando imagem

Tags: html, img, doctype

Terminei uma página pessoal, que contém 2 imagens. Porém ao fim disso, notei que havia esquecido de colocar o comando `!DOCTYPE html`. Ao inserí-lo, minhas imagens ficaram com uma linha embaixo:

[image: Sem DOCTYPE:]

[image: Com DOCTYPE:]

Como o `DOCTYPE` está influenciando nisso e o que posso fazer pra arrumar?

```
<img class="imgcontrol" src="pictures/me.jpg" alt="Foto de Matheus Pazzinato">
```

Comment: Esse Doctype é do HTML 5, certo? HTML5 tem algumas influências diferentes.

Comment: Coloque seu codigo para podermos vêr . Somente pela imagem não consigo te ajudar

Answer (score 2):

Quando vc não declara o `<!DOCTYPE>` o browser entra no **Quirks Mode**, isso significa que ele vai renderiza em alguma versão antiga do HTML, isso é usada quando vc precisa que um browser novo de suporte a uma site muito antigo.

Link para vc se informar mais: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode

Já com o `<!DOCTYPE>` definido, o browser renderiza com os Web Standards modernos. E uma das convenções é que a tag `<img>` por definição é um elemento do tipo `inline` ou seja, ela tem o compotamento de um texto comum, por isso a "margem" apareceu na imagem.

Para corrigir isso exitem várias soluções, ai vai depender da estrutura do seu código e do que vc quer para o layout. Mas o mais comum é definir a imagem como um elemento do tipo block tipo assim:

```
img {display:inline-block} /* esse é o padrão dos browser modernos */
```

Vc pode ler mais sobre isso aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Misc_top_level/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

Answer (score 0):

Para estilizar as imagens, estava criando uma Tag `div` com a tag `img` dentro e usando nela uma `class`. Por algum motivo, em HTML5 o espaçamento interno da `div` fica um pouco maior que do que a foto que eu insiro, criando essa "linha" que exibe a cor do background. Minha solução foi simplesmente excluir a `div`, e usar minha `class` dentro da tag `img`:

Antes:

```
  <div class="imgcontrol">
      <img src="pictures/me.jpg" alt="Foto de Matheus Pazzinato">
    </div>
```

Depois:

```
<img class="imgcontrol" src="pictures/me.jpg" alt="Foto de Matheus Pazzinato">
```